# How do you make jQuery bind events to elements loaded via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, binding, load

I'm using the .load() function to load a section of html that has some jQuery functionality that is bound to a certain class. =/

thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use live events:

```
$('.className').live(function(event) {
   ...
}
```

jQuery keeps a repository of all live selectors such as `.className` in this case. And it adds a handler to the document to listen for events that bubble up to the document. This special handler then basically runs through all the live selectors and forwards the event to those elements that match the live selectors, if any.

If any of the intermediate event handlers intercept the event and stop it from further propagating before it reaches up to the document, the `live` handlers will not be executed.

Comment: The live() function has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.
You should use use the on() function.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a click event this will be your syntax:

```
   $('a.myClass').live("click", function() {

        // do something here

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [JQuery's live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/). This allows you to:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now or in the future.

Comment: how do you use it? I havent had much success with live

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Like so:

```
$(".existingElement").on('click', '.addedByAjax .className', function(){
  // ... do whatever
}
```

Note that existingElement has to exist in the moment when this piece of code is going to run.
So you always have to bind to an element, to which you're going to load stuff by ajax *into*, and use the second selector (the one in the on() function) to match whatever is added.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually bind the events after you set the html.

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  $('.result a').click(function() {
    alert('click');
  });
});
```

Additionally you can use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to help with it.

Comment: Provide the HTML, AJAX resposne and JavaScript so we can see what exactly is not working.