# Datepicker is not working in AJAX JSF page

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with Datepicker. The problem is when I use AJAX to update the data into the page. After I execute AJAX action the page is datepicker is not working:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>       
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> Account Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </div>  
        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Account Profile"  style="position:relative"  value="resources/images/logo_account_profile.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:850px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:20px">

                    <h:form id="form">
                        <table>
                            <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{AccountProfileController.userData}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User ID</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.userid}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.userid}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Group ID</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.groupid}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText id="groupid" value="#{ud.groupid}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}"
                                                     validator="#{ValidatorController.validateEditGroupID}" autocomplete="off">                                        
                                            <f:ajax event="blur" render="groupidvalidator" />                                          
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        <h:message id="groupidvalidator" for="groupid" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Special Number</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.specialnumber}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.specialnumber}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.username}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.username}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="Encrypted" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.passwd}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date to change password</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.datetochangepasswd}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.datetochangepasswd}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Address</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.address}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.address}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>State/Region</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.stateregion}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.stateregion}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Country</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.country}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.country}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User Status</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.userstatus}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.userstatus}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Telephone</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.telephone}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.telephone}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date User Added</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateuseradded}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateuseradded}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User Expire Date</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.userexpiredate}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.userexpiredate}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Date User Locked</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.dateuserlocked}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText id="datetouserlocked" styleClass="datepicker" value="#{ud.dateuserlocked}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>City</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.city}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.city}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>E-mail</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.email}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.email}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Description</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ud.description}" 
                                                      rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                        <h:inputText value="#{ud.description}" rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" />
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>

                            </ui:repeat>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Insert this in order to use JGrown message-->                           
                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                        <h:commandButton value=" Edit Account " rendered="#{not AccountProfileController.editable}" action="#{AccountProfileController.editAccount(true)}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;                        
                        <h:commandButton value=" Save Account " rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" action="#{AccountProfileController.saveData}" update="growl">
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
                        <h:commandButton value=" Cancel " rendered="#{AccountProfileController.editable}" action="#{AccountProfileController.initDBData}" >
                            <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            //For calendar
                            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                                inline: true,
                                showWeek: true,
                                firstDay: 1,
                                dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'
                            });                            
                        </script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script> 

                    </h:form>

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:450px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:600px">

                </div>               

            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

I tested to remove the AJAX part - the datepicker is working properly. Can you tell me why AJAX prevents the JavaScript to work?

Comment: You are already using Primefaces components, why not just use the Primefaces Calendar component?  It is built using jQuery UI DatePicker and they have already went through the work of resolving the AJAX issues with this control.

Comment: Because I face this problem with Primefaces calendar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719452/how-to-change-input-field-style

Comment: You include some css that is affecting, primefaces. Find and remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this (do not replace your current code)

```
$(window).load(function () {
 jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
  if (data.status === 'success') {
       $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
             dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'
        });     
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: I tested the code - now I have reversed effect. The calender is working when I submit the form. But when I open the page and I click on the input field from the first time it's not working.

Comment: Yes, now it's working. Can you simplify the code? For example place the calendar into function and call it twice.

Comment: well you can wrap the the whole `$(".datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
             dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy'
        });     
        }` in a function and call it... in the posted above code there is nothing to simplify...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Datepicker might not work after AJAX update.

These link might be helpful.

[jQuery Datepicker does not work after Ajax Partial Postback](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/jquery-datepicker-does-not-work-after.html).

[jQuery date picker not persistant after AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801986/jquery-date-picker-not-persistant-after-ajax)

[Datepicker after Ajax Call not quite working - unexpected behavior?](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-after-ajax-call-not-quite-working-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: I looked at the examples. But I know very little about JavaScript and I don't understand how to repair my code.

Comment: You should change your javascript code, written inside the script tags as mentioned in the links above.

Comment: @user1285928: Try moving your datepicker script tag outside the `<h:form>`, at the end before `</h:body>`.