# jquery - dynamically created button not working

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code which inserts a link into a p tag when a date is selected from the datepicker.

For some reason the .click function of this dynamically created link does not work - but it does work if I hard code the button in exactly the same place rather than inserting it dynamically.

Any ideas why this is happening??

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#MR1 > #datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [(date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 4), ""] },
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: "Book now...",
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function(date) { $("#MR1 > #selecteddate").prepend("Date: " + $("#MR1 > #datepicker").val() + " - <a href='javascript:;' class='cleardate'>clear date</a>"); },
        dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
        altField: "#datepickeralt",
        altFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        navigationAsDateFormat: true,
        minDate: 0,
    });

    $("#MR1 > #selecteddate > .cleardate").click(function(){
        $("#MR1 > #selecteddate").html("");
        $("#MR1 > #datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);
        $("#MR1 > #datepickeralt").val("");
    });

});
```

body code as follows...

```
<div id="MR1">
<p id="selecteddate"></p>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" id="datepickeralt" disabled="disabled" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method instead.

```
$("#MR1 > #selecteddate > .cleardate").live('click',function(){
    $("#MR1 > #selecteddate").html("");
    $("#MR1 > #datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);
    $("#MR1 > #datepickeralt").val("");
});
```

jQuery events work from the DOM generated at the page load, and thus any dynamically generated content after is ignored. `.live()` uses the `body` element as context and finds any matches for the selector you specified, thus maintaining the "bind" after the content has been added.

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773573/jquery-ajaxed-content-losing-its-bind), it's a fairly common question.

Comment: The reason, why you need the live method is, that the element is not specified in the DOM at the beginning of the site. For all new elements during the runtime you need to use live() instead. Take a look onto the Caveats on the jQuery site, to see the differences: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `.live` instead of `.click` when dynamically adding elements.

```
$("#MR1 > #selecteddate > .cleardate").live('click',function(){
        $("#MR1 > #selecteddate").html("");
        $("#MR1 > #datepicker").datepicker("setDate", null);
        $("#MR1 > #datepickeralt").val("");
    });
```