# Ajax loads new button, do I need to load a new selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I'm coding a message system for example. Users can add messages (via AJAX) and next to their messages they've got some buttons. (Edit, Remove, ...)

By loading the page, a few messages are loaded.

```
<div class="message">
    <p>blaat</p>
    <a href="#" class="btnRemove">Remove</a>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <p>blaat</p>
    <a href="#" class="btnRemove">Remove</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery selector knows these elements. Because they already exist when I execute the jQuery script. (document.ready)
But when I add another "message", jQuery can't handle the 'remove' link because it's loaded after running the jQuery script.

Can somebody help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the JavaScript code with this example? off the top of my head I know the `$().live` function in jQuery would probably be a good fit for your needs as it will ensure the `handler` is added to the buttons when they are **magically** added to the `DOM`... See my Answer below :]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make jQuery bind events to elements loaded via Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413797/how-do-you-make-jquery-bind-events-to-elements-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: WHY LIVE WHEN YOU CAN [DELEGATE](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `live` method instead of `bind` (or the shorthand `click`). So it'd look like:

```
$('.btnRemove').live('click', function(e) { ... });
```

This uses event delegation, with the `click` event handler attached to `document` rather than any particular element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to work on remove which is loaded using ajax.

Answer (score -1):

can you post the JavaScript code with this example? off the top of my head I know the `$().live` function in jQuery would probably be a good fit for your needs as it will handle the buttons when they are added to the `DOM`... For example:

`$('.btnRemove').live('click', function(e) { ... });`

Comment: Hey guise!  What's going on in here?