# How bind events in jQuery 1.9.0 to elements loaded via Ajax?

Tags: jquery

I know that we could use "live" method for such purposes as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413797/how-do-you-make-jquery-bind-events-to-elements-loaded-via-ajax). But now "live" method is removed in jQuery 1.9.0. So how should I bind some event (for example, "click") for elements loaded by Ajax?

Comment: `on` as the docs tell you As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `.on()` for binding events:

## usage:

```
$(document).on('click', '.loaded-via-ajax', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This will alert the id of the elem which is loaded through ajax.

You have to delegate the events to the existing parent, like this:

```
$('.classofdiv').on('click', '.loaded-via-ajax', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

here `.classofdiv` is a div which has got content loaded from the ajax function and when you click the `elem` with class name `.loaded-via-ajax` this will get the event and finally alerts its id (*`if that elem has an id`*)

Comment: Thanks. Binding to the existing parrent element helped